# PaperTrail with STI appears to be storing wrong item_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

According to the [docs](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v10.3.1/README.md#5a-single-table-inheritance-sti) (and [specs](https://github.com/lorint/paper_trail/blob/master/spec/models/animal_spec.rb)) this STI setup below should work to log the history under my Agency subclass:

```
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
end

class Agency < Entity
  has_paper_trail
end
```

however, the item_type on the history is being stored as Entity and the version history is not working as expected

```
pry> Agency.create name:'My Org'
=> #<Agency:0x00007fab7b003740
 id: 103,
 type: "Agency",
 name: "My Org"
 ...
pry> Agency.last.version
  Agency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."type" = $1 ORDER BY "entities"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["type", "Agency"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
pry> Agency.last.versions
PaperTrail::Version Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_id" = $1 AND "versions"."item_type" = $2 ORDER BY "versions"."created_at" ASC, "versions"."id" ASC  [["item_id", 103], ["item_type", "Entity"]]
=> [#<PaperTrail::Version:0x00007fab72ec2118
  id: 222,
  item_type: "Entity",
  item_id: 103,
  event: "create",
  whodunnit: nil,
  object: nil,
  created_at: Mon, 29 Jun 2020 15:59:24 EDT -04:00,
  object_changes:
   {"id"=>[nil, 103],
    "name"=>[nil, "My Org"],
    "slug"=>[nil, "my-org"],
    "type"=>[nil, "Agency"],
    "created_at"=>[nil, "2020-06-29T15:59:24.344-04:00"],
    "updated_at"=>[nil, "2020-06-29T15:59:24.344-04:00"]}>]
```

Am I missing something or might this be a bug?

Rails 6.0.3.2, PaperTrail 10.3.1

Comment: To reproduce challenging stuff like this in isolation, I find [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug-report.md) really useful. If you can reproduce the issue with a script like this, please submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is mentioned in [issue #594](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/594), and if you establish an item_subtype column in your versions table then it provides a workaround.

If you instead want item_type to always refer to the subclass name -- for instance, "Agency" in your example -- then a fix is available by referencing this version of PaperTrail:

```
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'paper-trail-gem/paper_trail', ref: '91deff4324e079cc2af044d5b9471c5ceaa50191'
```

Reason this works is that this issue was fixed in mid-2018 in [PR 1108](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/pull/1108/files).  A month after it was committed though, the fix was reverted.  We've carried on using this older version of PaperTrail since then in a large-scale application, and it's worked out well.